# Taking limit points of a set is an idempotent operation

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X$ be a metric space and let $S \subset X$. We denote the set of limit points of $S$ as $L(S)$. I want to show that $L(L(S)) \subseteq L(S)$, that is, any limit point of the set of limit points of $S$ is a limit point of $S$. I've worked on it and come to a solution, but I'd just like some confirmation on whether it's correct.

Let $p \in L(L(S))$. Then every neighbourhood around $p$ will contain an element in $L(S)$. Let $x$ be one such element. Since $x \in L(S)$, then every neighbourhood around $x$ will contain an element in $S$. I want to say that this neighbourhood around $x$ is contained in the neighbourhood around $p$, but I don't know if I can make this jump.

Help is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always find a neighbourhood around $x$ that is contained in the neighbourhood around $p$.

Let $p\in L(L(S))$. If $p\in L(S)$, then done. If not, by the definition of accumulation points, for any neighborhood $G_1$ (open set) of $p$, there is $G_1\cap (L(S)-\{p\})\ne \varnothing$. Pick a $x\in G_1\cap L(S)$ and $x\ne p$.

If $x\in S$, then neighborhood of $p$ contains a point of $S$ and so $p$ is an accumulation point of $S$, or $p\in L(S)$, done. If not,  then there is a neighborhood $G_2$ of $x$ such that $\:G_2\cap (S-\{x\})\ne \varnothing$. Then choose $G'=G_2\cap G_1$. $G'$ is clearly open. Also $x\in G'$ and $G'\subset G_1$.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to choose a new neighborhood around $x$. In fact it doesn't work unless you use the same one.

The neighborhood $U$ of $p$ contains $x$. The same neighborhood $U$ is a neighborhood of $x$, so it contains an element of $S$. Since the choice of neighborhood was arbitrary we're done.

Comment: This is correct if neighborhoods are assumed to be open.  Some textbooks define a neighborhood of a point to be any set that includes an open subset containing the point.  Under that convention, one should use "open neighborhood" in place of "neighborhood" throughout this answer.

Comment: @Andreas I use Munkres' convention where all neighborhoods are open.